# CSS3: set background image to rel attribute value

Tags: css

I'm looking to set the `background-image` (or even render an image via the pseudo elements `:after` or `:before`) to the value, which will be a URL, of a `rel` attribute, but only in certain cases (this is a cloud file listing). For example:

HTML:

```html
<div class="icon ${fileExtension}" rel="${fileURL}"></div>
```

It would be great if I could do something like this:

CSS:

```
.icon.png,
.icon.jpg,
.icon.jpeg,
.icon.bmp,
.icon.gif { background-image: attr(rel,url);  }
```

... but obviously that doesn't work as, if I'm not mistaken, the `attr()` CSS function only works inside pseudo element blocks.

I know there are ways of doing this using conditional JSP or even jQuery logic, but I'd like to figure out a neat way of doing it via CSS3, since I'm only concerned with modern browsers at the moment anyway.

Also, I don't want to explicitly set the background image to the URL or create an `<img>` element, because by default if the file is not a supported image, I'd rather display a predetermined set of icons.

Comment: [The CSS3 spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attribute) allows `attr()` to be used anywhere else along with pseudo-elements and the `content` property. As for browser implementations... I haven't gotten around to testing that.

Comment: I've somehow never heard of `attr()`..

Comment: @thirtydot: It first appeared in the [CSS2 generated content spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/generate.html), and is useful for stuff like custom counters for lists. Except hardly anyone uses it yet because of the usual suspects.

Comment: attr() is quite powerful,  but it doesn't seem to work in this instance as @BoltClock suggests... hmm... am I just missing something obvious here?

Comment: @BoltClock: Do you happen to know if any browser (even partially) implements `attr` yet as described here? http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#functional

Comment: Dunno... I can't find sources anywhere in the entire Web that state browser support for CSS3-enhanced `attr()`, and my few minutes in jsFiddle haven't turned up any results in Firefox 5.

Comment: @BoltClock: I was testing with Chrome canary, and also no joy. It looks like the answer here is "it's not currently possible" :(

Comment: @thirtydot: Can't blame them. The **only** CSS3 module that's even a recommendation as of now is colors, and the **only** other one remotely close to it is... wait for it... selectors. Up to 10 years later, everything else is still a working draft. http://www.w3.org/Style/CSS/current-work

Comment: Just to clarify: as far as the CSS3 specification is concerned, you're using `attr()` correctly.

Comment: https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=26609 this is interesting, there is an initial implementation for CSS3 `attr()` in webkit back in  2009, there was an update in May 2011 with testcase which works in FF 4

Comment: @BoltClock thanks, I guess it's just a matter of browser support... looks like jQuery will have to come into play

Comment: You can't nest attr() inside url(). I believe this is why: "The ‘attr()’ expression cannot currently fall back onto another attribute. Future versions of CSS may extend ‘attr()’ in this direction." -- http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-values/#attr

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've decided to go the jQuery route, and used a combination of @ryanve and @stefanz answers. Thanks guys

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".png,.jpg,.jpeg,.bmp,.gif,.tiff").each(function(n) {
        var bg = 'url(' + $(this).attr("rel") + ')';
        $(this).css('background-image', bg);
    });
});
```

I think this is relatively neat/concise and works well for my needs. Feel free to comment on efficiency, methodology, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Using

```
.icon:after{ content: ""attr(rel)""; }
```

displays the `rel` value as text.

A jQuery solution is to add the `background-image` (taken from the `rel` value) as inline CSS:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    $('.icon').each(function() {
        var $this = $(this);
        $this.css('background-image', 'url(' + $this.attr('rel') + ')');
    });
});
```

Comment: Reason why that works is because that's the CSS2 version of `attr()` which has good support across other browsers and IE9. Additional checks need to be done in the JS code to match the selectors in the given CSS.

Answer (score 1):

I've tried to do something using jQuery but i don't exactly understand what you want so i can't go on with my code. So far i've done only this.

**EDITED** I hope it's exactly what you need

```
$(function(){
    var terms = new Array('png','jpg','jpeg','bmp','gif');

    $('.icon').each(function(){
        var t = $(this),
            rel = t.attr('rel'),
            cls = t.attr('class');

        cls = cls.split(' ');

        for (var i=0; i < terms.length; i++) {
            if (terms[i] == cls[1]) {
                t.css('background-image','url('+rel+')');
            }
        }
    });
});
```

if you can give me a better example, to undestand exactly what you want, i hope somebody from here will be able to solve your problem.

Regards, 
Stefan

Comment: Basically, if the element has any of the classes in `terms`, the OP wants to set the element's CSS `background-image` to whatever's in its `rel` attribute.

Comment: Looks good +1. As a little tidbit you can use `.hasClass()` instead, but your code works as is.